# Objects origin is not moving in edit mode

Tags: origin

I probably messed up some of the settings but I couldn't figure it out my selfe.
The problem is, that when I move the wohle mesh in edit mode the objects origin isn't moving with the object, but the pivot point is nevertheless still in the objects center.
And the reason I think the problem lies in the blender overall settings is because I started a new project and tried the same thing with the default cube. The problem is still the same.[image: Default start of the new project]
[image: Setup afer moving the object along the y-axis in edit mode]

Comment: No, that is intended, and important.  The object origin does not change with edit mode changes, only with object mode changes.  The reason that the center of edit-mode transformations change is because those are not centered on the object origin unless you use a cursor pivot, centered on that origin; they are probably using the median vertex position as the pivot instead.

Answer (score 2):

Pivot Point and Object Origin are different things.  The Object Origin isn't meant to move in edit mode.  The Pivot point depends on the Transform Pivot Point setting.  Take a look at the top bar in the 3D window: [image: top bar of 3d window]

The second drop down sets the pivot point: [image: Transform Pivot Point dropdown]

You haven't screwed up any settings.  You just have the Pivot Point set to "median point". Because you have selected a cube, the median point happens to be the center of the cube.

If you want to pivot along the object origin, change the drop down to "Individual origins".

To move the origin, in *object* mode, Right Click and select "Set Origin" from the popup menu[image: Object mode right click menu]

Comment: Would change this slightly to _"because you have selected **all vertices** of cube"_  .... as opposed to result of  (median point location) with one vert, one edge, one face selected etc.  (also individual origins will probably not be the object origin location)

Comment: Good point. I wasn't sure how much detail would be overwhelming.  One could write a longish essay on pivot points, coordinate spaces, and their interactions.